# Match a pattern not followed by a sub-pattern in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

Suppose I have a file with lines that contain the following strings:

```
...cat dog lorem ipsum...
...cat lizard ...
...cat bird ...
...cat dog ...
```

I want to write a regex that matches the lines in which `cat` is *not* followed by `dog`:

```
...cat lizard ...
...cat bird ...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 27):

Inversely match an atom by following it with `@!`. In this case, the atom we want to not-match is a capture group matching the string `dog`:

```
/\vcat (dog)@!
```

Broken down:

1. `\v` activates [very magic](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) parsing mode
2. `(dog)` matches the string `dog` and puts it in capture group 1
3. `@!` inverts the atom `(dog)`, so that the pattern matches when `dog` is *absent*

This matches instances of `cat` (and a trailing space) not followed by `dog`.

Comment: Without "very magic" mode: `/cat \(dog\)\@!`

Comment: what is your purpose to ask a question and answer it by yourself in a minute? and the Q&A is just make "another" example of doc `:h \@!`? I think the doc is good enough.

Comment: @Kent 1. To provide a clear statement of a question that I could not find a direct example of on Stack Overflow, and the answer that I found after searching for longer than I'd have had to if it had been asked and answered directly. This is explicitly encouraged by SO policy. 2. The doc is great if you know what to look for; I was here looking because I didn't already know.

Comment: Okay, I can understand if you don't know what to look for. there are number of ways to search the doc.  If I had problem, I would first search help/doc/manpage. well it is another situation if I don't know what I should look for. anyway, read `:h help` and `:h helpgrep` they may be helpful for you. But the Q&A is just another example of existing doc.  Answering selves questions is encouraged, but not repeating the manual/document. personally I even think the `foo bar` example in doc is more straightforward.

Comment: I know how to access the doc itself, but I wasn't sure what phrasing to use to find what I was looking for. I found it here in a tangentially-related question. If you think the doc's example is clearer, post it or link it here for folks to see. If you think the question should be closed or deleted because it is in conflict with SO policy, then move to close or delete it. I don't think debating this in the comments is helpful to folks who are just trying to get the question answered.

Comment: This is perfectly good practice in SO to self answer questions even if the answer to it is found somewhere else. This particular Qn saved 30 minutes for me, thanks @Stew.  Finding answers on SO via google is much easier and less painful than reading help on vim, especially when it comes to vim's tricky regex syntax!

Comment: @Stew How about match `{` not followed by `#@@`? Thanks in advanced!